# PostMan is working but http is giving 404 error in flutter

Tags: api, flutter, http, flutter-web

I am using following code for my api. This api is working in postman but showing 404 error code in http flutter.

My flutter code:

```
 RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            apiCall();
          },
          child: Text("Press"),
        )

  Future apiCall() async {
    var body =
        jsonEncode({"filepath": "patient/reports/1602333458533-Liver.jpg"});
    try {
      await http
          .post('http://3.6.197.52:3100/downloadFile',
              headers: {"Accept": "Application/json"}, body: body)
          .then((http.Response response) => print(response.statusCode));
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

It is giving error code 404 .

Following is postman result:

[Post Man result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzyQA.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the wrong headers. The `Accept` header is for determining which result type you expect from the server. From your screenshot (and the data) it seems quite clear, you would expect an `image/jpg`. On the other hand, you are missing the `Content-Type` header, which defines what type of data you are sending with your request, in your case `application/json`. So the server probably can't parse the body correctly.

Assuming, that `jsonEncode` is just something like `JSON.stringify` you should do something like the following

```js
Future apiCall() async {
    var body =
        jsonEncode({"filepath": "patient/reports/1602333458533-Liver.jpg"});
    try {
      await http
          .post('http://3.6.197.52:3100/downloadFile',
              headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}, body: body)
          .then((http.Response response) => print(response.statusCode));
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

Comment: did same json encode sending pdf file but still not working

Comment: @s.j 404 means the url you are using is not known at the server

Comment: passing same as passed in postman my api of post with 3 query params and one body params.

Comment: it's not live on local now

Comment: @s.j obviously you are not passing the same. If you were, you'd get the same response.

Comment: it is necesary to pass Content-Length in headers